# Short-circuit AND within IO Monad

Tags: haskell

I know the question has been asked [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012793/logical-and-strictness-with-io-monad) but I can't believe there is no straight answer.

I understand it's not good to hide side-effect inside a (&&) but in my case the side-effect are just checking something in the outstide world (existence of a file, check modification time etc, ask user a yes/no quistion).

So what is the haskell way to something like this, so that cond2 is not executed if cond1 is false.

```
cond1, cond2 :: IO bool


main = do
   cond <- liftM2 (&&) con1 con2
   if cond
   then   result1
   else   result2
```

I was expecting something like `cond <- all [con1, con2]` or equivalent, but I can't find anything.

## Update

I can see lots of manual solution. I'm still puzzled that this function doesn't exists somewhere.
One advantage of lazzy evaluation is it doesn't only short-circuit for hard-coded `&&` like in C. It is really strange that when in *imperative* mode, Haskell can't even short-circuit `&&`.
Although, all solution use somehow and if to short-circuit the evaluation. Is there not a way to make a generic lazzy `liftM2` ?

Comment: Without using any special combinators: `andM [] = return True` and then `andM (x:xs) = do b <- x; if b then andM xs else return False`

Comment: As I said below, `andM` is defined in the monad-loops library, where one expects to find things like this http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:andM

Comment: @Arthur didn't see the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't different from what some others are saying, but isn't it simplest just to emulate the definition of `and`:

```
 andM = foldr (&&&) (return True)
  where ma &&& mb = ma >>= \p -> if p then mb else return p
```

then we get, say:

```
 > let test1 = putStrLn "This test succeeds" >> return True
 > let test2 = putStrLn "This test fails" >> return  False
 > andM [test1,test2,undefined,undefined]
 This test succeeds
 This test fails
 False
```

If `andM` didn't 'short-circuit', then the undefined cell would have been evaluated and returned an exception.

It is a little irritating that `liftM2 (&&)` doesn't work as one hoped.

Edit: I just noticed that, as one might have expected, this is defined in the `monad-loops` package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.2.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Loops.html#andM

Answer (score 7):

This is what `Pipes.Prelude.and` does, going over a lazy stream of effectfully-generated conditionals and short-circuiting if any of them are `False`:

```
import Pipes (each)
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes

conds :: [IO Bool]
conds = ...

main = do
    cond <- Pipes.and (each conds >-> Pipes.sequence)
    print cond
```

Relevant links:

- [and](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.3/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html#v:and)
- [Pipes tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.3/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html)

Answer (score 4):

The operation you want is simple to define explicitly.

```
shortCircuitAnd :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool
shortCircuitAnd x y = do
   r1 <- x -- perform effect of x
   if r1 
     then y -- perform effect of y and return result
     else return False -- do *not* evaluate or perform effect of y
```

Of course, you can use this function infix as well, using backticks:

```
x `shortCircuitAnd` y == shortCircuitAnd x y
```

Comment: `r1 && r2` is actually `r2` since `r1` is guaranteed by the `if`. Hence, `do r1 <- x ; if r1 then y else return False` works.

Answer (score 3):

We can use a monad transformer like `MaybeT`, which is an instance of `MonadPlus`. The idea is to use `guard` to turn `False` results into `mzero`s that will halt the computation. And then we convert the resulting `Maybe` back into a `Bool`.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

effyand :: (Functor m, Monad m) => [m Bool] -> m Bool
effyand = fmap isJust . runMaybeT . mapM_ (lift >=> guard)
```

Comment: I think it's better to add a little explanation to your answer rather than leave a block of code.

Answer (score 3):

I'd define a monoid like

```
newtype AllM m = AllM { getAllM :: m Bool }

instance (Monad m) => Monoid (AllM m) where
    mempty = AllM (return True)
    mappend (AllM u) (AllM v) = AllM $
        u >>= \x -> if x then v else return False
```

and then  `getAllM . mconcat . map AllM $ [con1, con2]`.